# Excel corrupted

Tags: excel, vba

I have this issue constantly happening, a rather complex excel file that I used to update market data daily, it contains VBA and about 15~20 tabs.

It occurred sometimes that after doing minor changes (ie., changing chart formats) and the file no longer being able to open and return an error message: "Excel has stopped working".

My only solution was to use Dropbox to revert to previous version. But is there a technical solution to it?

Thank you.

Comment: You're not the first MS user having this problem, check [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/microsoft-excel-has-stopped-working/2e2691c9-0882-4ea5-8d5b-ac73d31f2c90) out.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some insane calculations with excel and multiple tabs, having formulas all over with rows and rows of data. What solved it for me was to get a new computer with an i7 processor and 16gigs of ram. Excel can be very heavy on the processor if you have a lot of formulas.

Also, we have found that 64 bit excel is superior to 32 bit excel with many tabs and calculations so my advice is make sure you have 64 bit and a good processor. Even one "minor" change can set off a chain reaction of recalculations depending on what is in your excel file and tabs.